# PHPExcel formula border thickness issue

Tags: php, excel, border, phpexcel

When I try to to set a medium border around a cell, it will not display properly (to be seen in the picture). After editting the cell without changing its value (enter cell editting and pressing enter) it is displaying properly.
I'm using Excel 2007.

[Screen before updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI3bc.jpg)

```
<?php
include 'mySQLconnect.php';


/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Sheet 1');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B2', '1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B2', '1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', '1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B4', '1');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B6', '=SUM(B2:B4)');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6')->applyFromArray(
    array('borders' => array(
        'bottom'    => array('style' =>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM),
        'right'     => array('style' =>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM),
        'left'      => array('style' =>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM),
        'top'       => array('style' =>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM)
    )
)
);

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="data.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using `allborders` instead.

your code will be :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6')->applyFromArray(
    array('borders' => array(
    'allborders'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM)
    )
);
```

or else, you can change the excel format on the `createWriter` to `Excel2007` .

Comment: I've tried it with allboarders, but the rersult is still the same. The bottom-border is thinner than the others. When I write a text instead of a formula into cell B6 all borders are displayed properly from the beginning. It seems to be a problem with PHPExcel or Excel 2007.

Comment: I need it for another project. The code above is only to depict the problem to the community. I've uploaded the test-file here: [link](http://tv-laufach.de/ExcelExportTest.php). May everyone open it and report his result here. I know that is is not a big problem, but it's annoying to manually editting the cell every time and the Excel display makes no good picture.

Comment: have you tried to change the excel format on the `createWriter` to `Excel2007` ?

Comment: When I set the `createWriter` to `Excel 2007` everything works fine. Thanks @Nue. I originally wanted to create a xls-file to sustain backward compatibility but now I think to leave it this way.

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in PHPExcel.
The problem is fixed with Version 1.8.1